# Filter and Arrange array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of object from query and I want to rearrange it, remove the duplicate name and push genre to one array with the same name.

```
const genres = [
  { movie_id: 95, genre: 'Biography' },
  { movie_id: 95, genre: 'Crime' },
  { movie_id: 95, genre: 'Thriller' },
  { movie_id: 96, genre: 'Romantic' },
  { movie_id: 96, genre: 'Adult' },
  { movie_id: 96, genre: 'Drama' },
  { movie_id: 97, genre: 'Adventure' },
  { movie_id: 97, genre: 'Action' },
  { movie_id: 97, genre: 'Drama' }
]
```

below is the expected result.

```
  const genres= [
    {
      movie_id: 95,
      genre: ['Biography', 'Crime', 'Thriller'],
    },
    {
      movie_id: 96,
      genre: ['Romantic', 'Adult', 'Drama'],
    },
    {
      movie_id: 97,
      genre: ['Adventure', 'Action', 'Drama'],
    },
  ];
```

I've been trying to remove the duplicate ids and push the genre to array but no luck. I'm new to javascript.

How do I format it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a map of all the movies, and use [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to ensure all genres are unique.

```js
const genres = [
  { movie_id: 95, genre: 'Biography' },
  { movie_id: 95, genre: 'Crime' },
  { movie_id: 95, genre: 'Thriller' },
  { movie_id: 96, genre: 'Romantic' },
  { movie_id: 96, genre: 'Adult' },
  { movie_id: 96, genre: 'Drama' },
  { movie_id: 97, genre: 'Adventure' },
  { movie_id: 97, genre: 'Action' },
  { movie_id: 97, genre: 'Drama' }
]

let result = Object.values(genres.reduce((map, el) => { 
    if (!map[el.movie_id]) {
        map[el.movie_id] = { movie_id: el.movie_id, genre: []};
    }
    if (!map[el.movie_id].genre.includes(el.genre)) { 
        map[el.movie_id].genre.push(el.genre);
    }
    return map;
}, {}))

console.log(result);
```